# wordpress.org tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for questions related to the wordpress.org site, e.g. the .org support forums etc, but people are using it to indicate they are using a self hosted site which is incorrect. Clearly the tag name isn't clear enough.

How can we improve this and make the tag clearer/more useful? Should it even remain as a singular tag?

Answer (score 3):

What is considered on-topic for a [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.org) tag? Working with the APIs from .org for plugins and themes maybe? Forum questions should go to the forum, plugin requirements and theme requirements should be tagged as [plugin-development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development) and [theme-development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-development) respectively. Nothing else comes to mind for .org on-topic subjects (feel free to make suggestions in the comments).

Maybe we rename the tag to `api-wordpress.org` and update the description to reflect this change.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tag is fine. The occasional misuse can be edited out. It's about more than just the API: It covers everything related to the organization of the development by the core devs, the administration of plugins and themes, the docs, translations and so on. I don't see a better name for now.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found the WordPress.org tag an oddity. After all, this is a WordPress ***Development*** QnA. Correct me if I missed anything, but I struggle to see many reasons to ask development questions about the dot org.

I wonder if the WordPress.org tag might not be a candidate for a fairly comprehensive community wiki question and answer pair.

Comment: I think having a nicely worded meta question with a curated answer that we can share is something we should do more often